# Detox: Do you need to call device.reloadReactNative before each test?

Tags: detox

It's unclear to me if it is necessary / best practice to call `device.reloadReactNative()` before a test runs in Detox. The examples make it seem like it is best practice but it's unclear to me.

For example calling it in the `beforeAll`, is this necessary?

```
describe('Example', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('render a tappable list of posts', async () => {...});
});
```

I read [here](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/react-native-end-to-end-testing-with-detox) that it is best practice to call it but I'm not sure about the reliability of the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the app state somehow to a familiar baseline, before starting a new test. You can relaunch your app, or even reinstall it, if you must, but those are far slower. Reloading RN is a nice shortcut for RN apps.